# Are there libraries or packages for creating .mobi files in a Java/Linux environment?

Tags: java, linux, kindle, mobipocket

I'm trying to find a solution that offers either a Java api for writing .mobi files for sending to a Kindle, or something that's scriptable given a Linux environment.  I have text data in a MySQL database that I want to offer as Kindle-friendly content.

I'd like to hear what tools people have used for this that work reasonably well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are Linux versions of the KindleGen tool available [from Amazon here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000234621).